# Only allow a certain amount of checked boxes in Laravel

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I have a list of ten simple check boxes that all look something like this:

```
 {{ Form::label('waterBox', 'Water:') }}
 {{ Form::checkbox('waterBox', 'yes'); }}

 {{ Form::label('calBox', 'Calories (kcal):') }}
 {{ Form::checkbox('calBox', 'yes'); }}
```

I don't want the user to be allowed to check more than 5 boxes before submitting the form. How can I make it so that after a sixth box is checked one of the others is unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomly unchecking other checkboxes is a little confusing to your users.

How about disabling the other checkboxes instead?

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

$checkboxes.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == 5) {
            $checkboxes.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    } else {
        $checkboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F57s9/1/

---

**P.S.** If you're not using jQuery, just let me know and I'll whip you up a native solution.

Comment: I agree with Joseph, the use case is confusing to the end-user. As a general rule you should never programmatically alter what the user entered, as it throws them for a huge loop. (I was just up for the challenge of making it work.) :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a ver novice programer so Ill take an advice I can get. By the way I had to include `$(window).load(function(){` in order to get it to work properly, might want to add for anyone else who takes a look.

Comment: @TannerQuigley - either put the JS at the end of your document (before the closing `body` tag) or use `$(document).ready(function (){ /* code here */ })`.

Answer (score 1):

You could call a javascript function (I'm using jQuery in this example) that looks at all the waterBox checkboxes and limits it to 5, something like this:

```
    function limitCheckboxes()
    {
        var checkedBoxCount = $('[name=waterBox]:checked').length;
        $('[name=waterBox]:checked').each(function () {
            if ((checkedBoxCount > 5) &&
                (this.checked))
            {
                this.checked = false;
                checkedBoxCount--;
            }
        });
    }
```

Then be sure to name your checkboxes with brackets:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('waterBox', 'yes', false, ['onclick' => 'limitCheckboxes()']); }}
```

I haven't tested this, but the general principle should work.

**Update:** fixed missing ID attribute on checkbox.

**Update 2:** fixed jQuery selection of checkboxes and counts.

**Update 3:** fiddle around and got a working example going. The code above should now reflect that. :) Added fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/Miggl/XKB7b/

Comment: Sorry but I had no problem checking all 10 boxes. I should note that not all the Forms will have the name 'waterBox' but I don't know if that effects your answer.

Comment: You will have to create a function for each page, or perhaps pass in the name of the checkboxes as a second attribute. My updated code above considered all checkboxes, so it will uncheck the first checkbox it finds checked if someone checks more than 5 of any checkboxes on the page.

Comment: The checkbox's only appear on one page so that shouldn't be a problem. I tried your most updated piece of code and I was still able to check all boxes.

Comment: Excuse my phrasing. Yes none of them are being unchecked, I can check all ten at once.

Comment: I'm working on making a functional example. Should have something shortly.